# Problem building Ruby on Mac OSX Snow Leopard

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I'm having an issue compiling (make) ruby on Mac Osx . I get the following error:
compiling racc/cparse

> mkdir -p
>   ../../../.ext/i686-darwin10.2.0/racc
>   gcc -I. -I../../.. -I../../../.
>   -I../../.././ext/racc/cparse -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=1  -fno-common -pipe -fno-common   -c cparse.c cc -dynamic -bundle
>   -undefined suppress -flat_namespace -o ../../../.ext/i686-darwin10.2.0/racc/cparse.bundle
>   cparse.o -L. -L../../.. -L.     -lruby
>   -lpthread -ldl -lobjc   compiling readline gcc -I. -I../.. -I../../.
>   -I../.././ext/readline -DHAVE_READLINE_READLINE_H -DHAVE_READLINE_HISTORY_H -DHAVE_RL_FILENAME_COMPLETION_FUNCTION -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_MATCHES -DHAVE_RL_DEPREP_TERM_FUNCTION -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_APPEND_CHARACTER -DHAVE_RL_BASIC_WORD_BREAK_CHARACTERS -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETER_WORD_BREAK_CHARACTERS
>   -DHAVE_RL_BASIC_QUOTE_CHARACTERS -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETER_QUOTE_CHARACTERS -DHAVE_RL_FILENAME_QUOTE_CHARACTERS -DHAVE_RL_ATTEMPTED_COMPLETION_OVER -DHAVE_RL_LIBRARY_VERSION -DHAVE_RL_EVENT_HOOK -DHAVE_RL_CLEANUP_AFTER_SIGNAL -DHAVE_REPLACE_HISTORY_ENTRY -DHAVE_REMOVE_HISTORY  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=1  -fno-common -pipe -fno-common   -c readline.c readline.c: In function
>   ‘username_completion_proc_call’:
>   readline.c:730: error:
>   ‘username_completion_function’
>   undeclared (first use in this
>   function) readline.c:730: error: (Each
>   undeclared identifier is reported only
>   once readline.c:730: error: for each
>   function it appears in.) make[1]: ***
>   [readline.o] Error 1 make: *** [all]
>   Error 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=In+function+username_completion_proc_call:+readline.c:730:+error:+username_completion_function+undeclared&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8